# Looking for Encryption and Decryption method without special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I am having a hard time finding a **Encryption** and **Decryption** method for **ASP.NET**.

I have a website with a button that redirects to a download page like this:

www.example.com/downloads/1/filename.jpg

Where 1 = the id.

I want the id to be encrypted to something like this:

www.example.com/downloads/k0sjD3ks0x/filename.jpg

I want to do this with a encryption that **does not uses special characters like * / = +** , because these will "disturb" the link and it will try to navigate to a page that does not exist.

The problem is that almost all encryption methods (besides hexadecimal and MD5) return a encrypted string with these special characters. I don't want to use hexadecimal because an id of 1 will be encrypted to something like 32, and I believe MD5 cannot be decrypted (correct me if I'm wrong).

So if anyone knows of a encryption without special characters or wrote one himself and is willing to share, I'll appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would also consider using standard authentication and authorization methods if that is something you want to achieve.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this, as opposed to just protecting the resource with standard practices as oleksii suggests?

Comment: because I want to pass the id so that I can use it in another page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you want to use hexadecimal?

**If the id is always a cryptogram, you know that 32 is not decimal 32 but hexadecimal 32.**

Encode the cryptogram as hexadecimal. Hexadecimal does not include special characters.

Crypto algorithms output binary. You need to encode this binary to a string. It doesn't matter what crypto algorithm you use, you only need to encode the binary the algorithm outputs.

Alternatively, url encode the string cryptogram:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("cryptogram with special chars");
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I did not even thought of that. It works where I use AES string and encode it to hexadecimal.